# What is the correct way of handling different server responses on an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call. 
I want to do different things based on a server response.
But what happens if I got a 200 response?, will the code execute the 200 status code function?, or will it execute the succes function?, or both?
What would be the cleanest way of handling the responses?

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        accept: "application/json",
        headers: {APP_KEY: 'an app key'},
        data: 
        { 
            email: myresp.email
        },
        statusCode: 
        {
            200: function(xhr) 
            {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            204: function(xhr) 
            {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
        },
        success: function (result) 
        {
            console.log();
        },
        error: function (e) 
        {
             // log error in browser
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This isn't plain ajax. What library are you using?

Comment: jquery version 3.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For **backward compatibility** with `XMLHttpRequest`, a `jqXHR` object will expose the following properties and methods:*

- *...*
- *statusCode( callbacksByStatusCode )*

So, both ways work but you shouldn't mix them. [STFM](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Perfect, so I should treat the codes in the succes function.